# Text.BoringLayout WIDTH is set to 0 (not showing) in Android TextView When I have an non-English text?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, arabic, persian

I have an Android Widget TextView, when I setText with Persian charachters, it just not showing! and I guess the mBoring (Text.BoringLayout property) is responsible, because the width is set 0.
there is no problem when I set english + persian strign, and the width set to proper value such as 210.

```
mSubjectTextView = new TextView(mContext);
mSubjectTextView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
mSubjectTextView.setSingleLine(); // allow partial words to be elided
mSubjectTextView.setIncludeFontPadding(false);
ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(mSubjectTextView, 1);
ViewUtils.setTextAlignment(mSubjectTextView, View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START);

Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(),
        "fonts/byekan.ttf");
mSubjectTextView.setTypeface(face);

mSubjectTextView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(subjectWidth, subjectHeight));
mSubjectTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, mCoordinates.subjectFontSize);
    layoutViewExactly(mSubjectTextView, subjectWidth, subjectHeight);


mSubjectTextView.setText("سلام");

canvas.translate(mCoordinates.subjectX, mCoordinates.subjectY);
mSubjectTextView.draw(canvas);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try displaying your text via HTML:

```
mSubjectTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("سلام"));
```

Comment: @paykoob tested with the default settings and it works. Try avoiding the custom typeface and see if that fixes your problem, if it does you'll at least know where to look.

Comment: thanks to your guide, I remove the setSingleLine and it's just working. But what's the problem?